# Как получить значения инпутов чтобы использовать дальше в классе для валидации?

Tags: javascript, typescript, input, ecmascript-6

```js
const form = document.forms[0]


form.addEventListener('submit', (e:any) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   const formData = new FormData(e.target)
   const formProps = Object.fromEntries(formData)
   console.log(formProps)
   
})
```

```html
<div class="form">
      <h2>Callback form</h2>
      <form class="callback__form" action="#" method="post">
         <div class="name">
            <label for="userName"><span>Name*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
         </div>
         <div class="tel">
            <label for="userTel"><span>Tel*</span></label>
            <input type="tel" name="userTel" id="userTel">

         </div>
         <div class="mail">
            <label for="userMail"><span>E-mail*</span></label>
            <input type="email" name="userMail" id="userMail">
         </div>
         <div class="message">
            <label for="userMessage"><span>Message</span></label>
            <textarea name="userMessage" id="userMessage"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="controls">
            <div class="submit">
               <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
            <div class="reset">
               <button type="reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
         </div>        
      </form>
```

Comment: let val = input.value

Comment: А что с текущим кодом не так?

Comment: Так не работает, у инпута изначально value это пустая строка... Значение value надо получить в методе класса, не могу получить доступ к значению length для последующей валидации...